# Angular filter doesn't filter every column only one at a time

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement, filter, angular-material

### **INTRO**

I'm trying to implement that my Angular column filter doesn't show my previously filtered results once I filter one column. More that it keeps on filtering results as I select more items in my column filters.

Let's say I select a name from my Name column and it filters fine (which it does), but as soon as I select a different column filter (let's say Project) it adds everyone else that's previously been filtered out and filters what I need (filters the Projects), same for Project Activity, and it just adds more and more items that are filtered but keeps the old filtered mess.

I just have no idea how to implement a mechanism that blocks the filter from adding wrong items to my filtered columns.

### **CODE**

There are 5 columns in my **HTML**:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="work_date" matSortDirection="asc">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="create_by">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let log"> {{ log.create_by }} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="project_id">
                <mat-header-cell ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter: search)" *matHeaderCellDef
                    mat-sort-header>
                    Project ID </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let log"> {{ getSecondArrayItem(log.project_id)?.name }} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="project_activity_id">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Project Activity ID </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let log"> {{ getPAItem(log.project_activity_id)?.name }} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="work_date">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Work date </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let log"> {{formatingDate(log.work_date)}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="hours">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Hours </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let log"> {{log.hours}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="minutes">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Minutes </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let log"> {{log.minutes}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="notes">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Additional notes </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let log"> {{log.notes}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
```

And this would be my **filter** in the component, **createFilter** is the main focus where all the logic for filtering columns and main filter logic occurs.

```
filterChange(filter, event) {
    //let filterValues = {}

    if (this.hasFilter) {
      // second filter
      console.log("second filter");
      this.filterValues[filter.columnProp] = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase().toString();
      console.log(this.filterValues);

      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
      console.log(this.dataSource.filter);

    } else {
      console.log("first filter");
      this.filterValues[filter.columnProp] = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase().toString();
      console.log(this.filterValues);

      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValues);
      console.log(this.dataSource.filter);
      this.hasFilter = true;
    }
  }

createFilter() {
    if (this.hasFilter) {
      // second filter - multi-layer filter

    } else {

      let filterFunction = function (data: any, filter: string): boolean {
        let searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
        let isFilterSet = false;
        for (const col in searchTerms) {
          console.log(searchTerms);
          console.log(col);
          if (searchTerms[col].toString() !== ' ') {
            isFilterSet = true;
          } else {
            delete searchTerms[col];
          }
        }

        console.log(searchTerms);

        let nameSearch = () => {
          let found = false;
          if (isFilterSet) {
            for (const col in searchTerms) {
              console.log(searchTerms[col]);

              if (searchTerms[col] == data[col].toString().toLowerCase() && isFilterSet) {
                found = true;
                console.log(this.nameSearch + " nameSearch");
                console.log(this.filterFunction + " filterFunction");
              } else {
                if (filterFunction == undefined) {
                  return found == true;
                }
              }
            }
            return found
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return nameSearch()
      }
      return filterFunction
    }
  }
```

My data source is my database and it connects absolutely fine with it, as well as filters one column at a time.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to be honest here, my solution is probably not the best, but here is the solution I found during one of my projects:

1. For each column, create an input using a reactive form and subscribe to its valueChange event.
2. Create a key: value object to store your search terms per column. It should look like {column1: columnFilter, column2: filter}... etc.
3. Populate it with your filters terms based on what you caught in valueChange event.
4. Override datasource filter by your own filtering function
5. Make sure that your new filtering method applies your filters depending on column, basically by using a switch case.